# Is there a way to listen that there are no events that are being raised in Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have **a requirement to turn off a certain feature** when the user starts typing which is simple. And when the user stops typing, **I want to turn the feature back on.**

Without reactive extensions, one can simply implement this feature with a `timer` that resets the timer on every **last keystroke** to `1 second` and when the `user stops typing and timer elapses` the **feature is turned back on**.

Is there any method I can call to achieve the same effect with `Reactive Extensions`?

`Throttle` or `Timeout` keeps calling the subscriber/exception action every `1 second`

**UPDATE**

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox MaxHeight="1000" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="meh"/>
```

***Extension class***

```
public static IObservable<EventArgs> ObserveTextChanged(this RichTextBox rtb)
{
 return Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, EventArgs>(
            h => rtb.TextChanged += h,
            h => rtb.TextChanged -= h)
                         .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs);
}
```

***Class*** where `meh` is the `RichTextBox`

```
public class MainWindow()
{
 //Change this to be the keypress/propertychagned event. The type T doesn't matter we ignore it
 var typing = meh.ObserveTextChanged().Take(4);
 var silence = meh.ObserveTextChanged().IgnoreElements();
 var source = typing.Concat(silence).Concat(typing);
 var disableSpellcheck = source.Select(_ => false);
 var enableSpellcheck = source.Select(_ => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                                     .Switch()
                                     .Select(_ => true);

 disableSpellcheck.Merge(enableSpellcheck)
                  .DistinctUntilChanged()
                  .Subscribe(SetFlag);

 }

// Define other methods and classes here
public void SetFlag(bool flag)
{
 Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => SpellCheck.SetIsEnabled(meh, flag)));
 Debug.Write("flag");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is all the code to show how the code above could be ported to WPF. It appears that there is a gap in communication here, so I have created the whole wpf app to prove the point.

```
<Window x:Class="StackoverFlow_23764884.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="When checked, spellcheck is enabled (emulated)">
            <CheckBox x:Name="spellChecking" IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="False"/>
        </HeaderedContentControl>

        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Type here to see the Spellcheck enable and disable">
            <RichTextBox x:Name="meh" Width="400" Height="300" />
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace StackoverFlow_23764884
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var source = meh.ObserveTextChanged();
            var disableSpellcheck = source.Select(_ => false);
            var enableSpellcheck = source.Select(_ => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                                         .Switch()
                                         .Select(_ => true);

            disableSpellcheck.Merge(enableSpellcheck)
                             .DistinctUntilChanged()
                             .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                             .Subscribe(isEnabled => spellChecking.IsChecked=isEnabled);
        }

    }

    public static class ObEx
    {
        public static IObservable<EventArgs> ObserveTextChanged(this RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            return Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, EventArgs>(
                h => rtb.TextChanged += h,
                h => rtb.TextChanged -= h)
                .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

I pulled in the Rx-WPF nuget packeage will pulled everything else required for the code. This is .NET 4.5.

This is a sample to show how to solve the problem. i.e. I don't recommend using `.ObserveOnDispatcher()`, I dont recommend writing code-behind, and I know that setting IsEnabled on a checkbox is not *actually* doing a spellcheck. I am hoping that this is enough to the audience to recreate their actual solution.

I do hope it helps though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it actually worked! Why you don't recommend using `ObserveOnDispatcher`? What if it is a custom control to be used though, `MVVM` is completely different usage for a custom control as the `SpellCheck` is an attach property that I don't own or should not be in the `ViewModel`.

Comment: I would suggest using `ObserveOn(IScheduler)` and passing in a dispatcherScheduler (for testing). See http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#TestingRx. Next I would use MVVM, have a property called `SuppressSpellCheck` and bind that to your AttachedProperty. Now the Rx query above just toggles that to enable/disable your spellchecking. If you dont Unit test, then ignore all of this :-)

Answer (score 3):

Great question.

There are probably many ways to solve this, but here is one that you can work with. First we need the source observable sequence. This is probably a keypressed event or property changed event that has been converted to an Observable sequence using FromEvent or some other factory/conversion or maybe ReactiveUI.

In this sample I will use `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)).Take(4);` as a substitute for the source sequence (just to prove the concept).

Next, we need to decide when we need to disable the feature (SpellCheck?). This is when the source sequence yields a value.

`var disableSpellcheck = source.Select(_=>false);`

Then we need to decide when we need to re-enable the feature. This is when there has been 1 second of silence on the source sequence. One trick you can do to implement this is to create a One Second timer for each event from the source. When a new Timer is created, cancel the previous one. You can do this by creating a nested observable sequence, and using Switch to cancel previous inner sequences when a new one it produced.

```
var enableSpellcheck = source.Select(_=>Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
      .Switch()
      .Select(_=>true);
```

Now we want to merge these two sequences, and push the result to method that enables/disables the feature.

```
Observable.Merge(disableSpellcheck, enableSpellcheck)
          .Subscribe(isEnabled=>SetFlag(isEnabled));
```

However, as noted above, this call SetFlag(false) every time the source sequence yileded a value. This is easily solved by using the `DistinctUntilChanged()` operator.

The final sample (LinqPad) code is as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    //Change this to be the keypress/propertychagned event. The type T doesn't matter we ignore it
    var typing = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)).Take(4);
var silence = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).IgnoreElements();
var source = typing.Concat(silence).Concat(typing);

    var disableSpellcheck = source.Select(_=>false);
    var enableSpellcheck = source.Select(_=>Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
        .Switch()
        .Select(_=>true);

    Observable.Merge(disableSpellcheck, enableSpellcheck)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Subscribe(isEnabled=>SetFlag(isEnabled));

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public void SetFlag(bool flag)
{
    flag.Dump("flag");
}
```

Comment: Hi Lee, I tried your code and replaced Observable.Interval with Keypress. I don't get the desired result though when the user starts typing again, it doesn't publish to the subscribers to re-enable or disable spellcheck. It only did it once (enable/disable) and that's it

Comment: I have updated the code to prove that it works when there is a series of event in quick succession, some silence, then more events in quick succession. If you show the code you are actually using, I can point out the mistake.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using? That looks like you cut and paste code from this answer and then just renamed some strings? There is a method declared outside of the class, for example. You have method level code inside the class. the code posted wouldn;t even compile. I am happy help, if you are happy to at least try.

Comment: It's a WPF application that has a `RichTextBox`  called `meh` and I just changed what you said to KeyPress. So pretty much it'll look the same as your sample. That's the actual code that I am using:) I updated it with the `XAML`

Comment: Ok. Clearly a communication break down ;-). My sample was a LinqPad script that I hoped you would be able to see was emulating typing by mixing events with slience. I have posted a full solution for you below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this example](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc30) with [Throttle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) solves a similar problem.

So something along the lines might work for you too:

```
var throttled = observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
using (throttled.Subscribe(x => RestoreThing())) {}
```

Comment: Say it's a `TextChanged` where I turn off `SpellCheck` when user starts typing and if user hasn't type anything then I need to turn on `SpellCheck` back. I don't think just using `Throttle` will achieve what I want. It will just turn off the feature but I need to turn it back on

Comment: Also, it'll keep firing every 1 second which I don't want. I just want the last one.

Comment: @lll I think if you Throttle the same TextChanged and subscribe to that with turning SpellCheck on, it will work as expected.

Comment: Is there a way for it to do something like >---------|(event stop)--|1000---> ms publish to subscribers.

Comment: I thought you want to fire the event each time the typing stops. Throttle should not fire the event for every 1 second, it kind of filters and waits the events, not generating new events. Which version of Rx do you use?

Comment: The throttle will keep publishing to the subscribers. I'm using the latest Rx version. It keeps firing if I keep the key press on hold, every 1 second it publishes

Comment: I have to admit I am clueless. Could you share how you try to use it? (This image with Java version suggests it is fired after a certain time interval and only the last item from that interval: https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#throttlewithtimeout-or-debounce) The Distinct/DistinctUntilChanged (http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/05_Filtering.html#Distinct) might solve the repeated events problem.

Comment: Distinct will keep listening and firing every given time, it's like Event.Given(1 second).Last().Subscribe() that's something that I want :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm no RX master, but I've created a sample WinForms app that seems to work. On the form, I have `textBox1` and `button1` and that's it.

Here's the code-behind:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern(
                s => textBox1.TextChanged += s, s => textBox1.TextChanged -= s)
                //make sure we are on the UI thread
                .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                //immediately set it to false
                .Do(_ => UpdateEnabledStatus(false))
                //throttle for one second
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
                //again, make sure on UI thread
                .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                //now re-enable
                .Subscribe(_ => UpdateEnabledStatus(true));
        }

        private void UpdateEnabledStatus(bool enabled)
        {
            button1.Enabled = enabled;
        }
```

This works as you want, and does not hit the `UpdateEnabledStatus` method every second, at least in my testing.

Comment: So does it mean while it's observing it keeps calling UpdateEnableStatus(false)?

Comment: No, as I stated in my answer, I saw no evidence of `UpdateEnableStatus` being hit every second (I sat there with a breakpoint on it)

Comment: Tried your solution, it keeps hitting Do(_ => ...). Every 1 second. :s

Comment: @lll how does your application differ from my sample app?

Comment: I'm using `WPF`, also try enabling `SpellCheck` when user stops typing. And vice versa

Comment: @lll I'll try it with WPF

Comment: @lll Done in WPF, same behavior as I saw before. The `UpdateEnabledStatus` is not hit every second. Is there some other detail of your app that is relevant here?

Comment: Keep firing a keypress and don't release it. It keeps firing on the observers the UpdateEnableStatus

Comment: @lll I don't know how to account for that wrinkle, if that behavior is that detrimental to your application, then you'll have to hope somebody who knows more about RX responds